# Mule ESB: Not able to get older version of SAP Jco jars from SAP for Mule SAP Connector

Tags: mule, mule-studio, sap-erp, mule-el, jco

We have a requirement to connect SAP ERP. As per [Mule documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/SAP+Connector), to connect SAP (JCo jars) it says 3.0.11 (Latest) is not supported by the connector.

We have reached SAP - they say like only Latest version (3.0.11) should be downloaded from Market place. They were not supporting the SAP old version jars since latest is released (with bug fixed).

Please suggest, how do we get older version of jars (3.0.9 or 3.0.6). It will be very helpful. We are looking for options.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAP do not release older versions of the SAPJCO or SAPIDOC libraries as the latest versions are fully backward compatible.

The difference between 3.0.9 and 3.0.11 are very minor bug fixes, so its surprising to hear that 3.0.11 does not work.  MuleSoft should liaise directly with SAP as they are an SAP Certified Integration Partner and their software should always run on the latest versions of the various SAP connectors.

As a certified partner MuleSoft will be abundantly aware that customers only have access to the most recent versions of the SAPJCO/IDOC libraries, and that SAP do not release older versions.

You would also think that MuleSoft would have access to older versions of the libraries from engagements with existing/previous SAP customers.

I would advise you to go back to MuleSoft and have them speak directly with SAP.  This is not a problem for the customer.